# Is there a method in Spark to obtain an RDD which is a random subset, of a given exact size, of another RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I know RDD's have the 'sample' method which returns a new RDD containing a given fraction of the original RDD, randomly selected. However, as each element is selected randomly, the size of the new RDD is not deterministic.
There's also the 'takeSample' method which returns an input integer number of elements of an RDD. However, this returns a list rather than a new RDD.

Is there a method that returns an RDD with a specified exact number of randomly selected elements? Of course one can use takeSample and create a new RDD from that, but this means sending a lot of data back and forth between driver and executors.

Comment: I would combine an approximate, slightly oversized .sample (use a ratio of .count) with a simple .limit, to cut off any elements above your target size. If you .sample sufficiently closely to your target size, cutting off a few stragglers should'nt have any significant statistical impact on the result.

Answer (score 0):

It will expensive but you can sort by random number:

```
import os
import binascii
import random

rdd  = spark.sparkContext.range(100)

def with_rand(iter):
    random_ = random.Random(int(binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(4)), 16))
    for x in iter:
        yield random_.random(), x

rdd_sorted = rdd.mapPartitions(with_rand).sortByKey()
```

remove random number, add index and filter

```
n = 42

result = rdd_sorted.values().zipWithIndex().filter(lambda x: x[1] < n).keys()
```